# ошибка mixed content google chrome

Tags: ssl

здравствуйте, есть сайт который работает полностью только на https, и есть загрузка php скрипта со стороннего ресурса путем javascript (рекламный блок), но дело в том что там сайт работает только на http, и появляется ошибка которую я указал в заголовке, можно ли это как то обойти, не меняя обоим сертификаты?

Comment: Обойти нельзя. А зачем "обоим менять сертификаты"? Надо второй сайт переводить на https, и все.

Answer (score 0):

Обойти так не получится. Не особо понял, что там у тебя за рекламный блок. Попробуй сначала его загрузить с помощью php file_get_contents или curl, а затем уже его выводи с помощью js. Обычно такая ошибка возникает из-за вывода картинок с других сайтов у которых в href или src иcпользуется как раз http. Ты можешь их тоже сначала скачивать на свой сервер и затем уже выводить их. И вообще желательно бы код увидеть.

Comment: это рекламная сеть, по этому я не уверен что получится сделать как ты сказал

Comment: Я так делал множество раз с различными плагинами. И всем что берется с других ресурсов. Уверен тебе стоит попробовать этот вариант если хочешь избавится от ошибки. Если file_get_contents сработает далее от тебя требуется рутинная работа. И будет все выводится точно также только уже с твоего сервера.